# Easiest way to implement PUT API method to update entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web Api project and currently updating an entity is done via POST. Creating an entity is also done via the same POST method, and I implement by checking if the user has sent me an entity Id and then implementing an update as opposed to a create.

This is bad good for a number of obvious reasons. It's also confusing from a client perspective and makes the whole method slow and hard to define.

So I'm splitting updating into a PUT method, and I want it to be like so (psuedo code)

```
public string PUT(MyModel model){

    //Check if model Id is sent. return if not.


    //Check what other fields have been sent.


    //Update only those fields using EF and save.

    }
```

I would implement like:

```
var toUpdate = context.MyModels.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == model.Id);

if(toUpdate == default(MyModel)){ //Return error to client }

if(model.first != null){ toUpdate.first = model.first; }
//Repeat for every field.

context.MyModels.AddOrUpdate();
context.SaveChanges();
```

As I'm new to building API's I wondered if this is standard for creating PUT update methods. This might get closed as Opinion-based but I'd like to know if this implementation is okay as I've had no guidance in building this API really.

Comment: Check how you can utilize `Delta<T>` in your `Web Api`. I hope [this article](http://www.strathweb.com/2013/01/easy-asp-net-web-api-resource-updates-with-delta/) will help you get started and give you some idea how you can use `Delta<T>` with your `PUT` method.

Comment: @Michael Thanks this is really interesting. Just curious, what are the reasons for the patch method when in my PUT method above can update from a partial model anyway? Is it just convention or is there something more concrete?

Answer (score 0):

For your case, I think you can implement like this.

```
try
{
    context.Entry<MyModel>(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
{
    var msg = dbEx.EntityValidationErrors.Aggregate(string.Empty, (current1, validationErrors) => validationErrors.ValidationErrors.Aggregate(current1, (current, validationError) => current + (Environment.NewLine + $"Property: {validationError.PropertyName} Error: {validationError.ErrorMessage}")));
    var fail = new Exception(msg, dbEx);
    throw fail;
}
```

Actually, I prefer putting update code inside `generic` class, so that I don't need to write the update code for every entity

```
public void DoUpdate<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class
{
    try
    {
        Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
    {
        var msg = dbEx.EntityValidationErrors.Aggregate(string.Empty, (current1, validationErrors) => validationErrors.ValidationErrors.Aggregate(current1, (current, validationError) => current + (Environment.NewLine + $"Property: {validationError.PropertyName} Error: {validationError.ErrorMessage}")));
        var fail = new Exception(msg, dbEx);
        throw fail;
    }
}
```

Comment: Say if my user had passed an incomplete model, and so certain values were null, would this create null values against certain fields in my database? @kienct89

Comment: @JonnyKnottsvill: yes it will create null values if the column is nullable